# How to scrape fetch data from multiple pages and display in one page using Puppeteer and Cheerio?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

I try to scrape data from two different webpage and display/compare in my own page. It works fine for display data from one website, and crashed when I add another URL.(well, still display the information get from 1st website but keep blank for 2nd one)
so how to write the code to get data from multiple websites?
here is code

```
//modules for express, path, ejs, puppeteer, cheerio

//steup const
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const path = require('path')

let browser;
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//async getData
async function getData(url, page){
    try{
       await page.goto(url, {waitUnitl : 'load', timeout : 0})
       const html = await page.evaluate( () => document.body.innerHTML);
       const $ = cheerio.load(html);
       let text1 = $("#feature-bullets > ul > li:nth-child(6) > span").text();
       let text2 = $("#feature-bullets > ul > li:nth-child(8) > span").text();
       let text3 = $("#feature-bullets > ul > li:nth-child(10) > span").text();
       let text4 = $("#feature-bullets > ul > li:nth-child(9) > span").text();
       let img = $("#landingImage").attr("src");
       let aprice = $("#priceblock_dealprice").text();
       let aunit = $("#variation_style_name > div > span > span.a-truncate-cut > span").text();
       let ashipping = $("#deliveryMessageMirId > b").text();
       let awarranty = $("#creturns-policy-anchor-text").text();
       let eprice = $("#a-autoid-10-announce > span.a-color-base > span").text();
       return{text1, text2, text3, text4, aprice, aunit, ashipping, awarranty, img, eprice}
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
}

//routes
app.get('/results', async function(req, res){
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : true})
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //calling the getData function and sending URL and the page
    let data = await getData('https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-Deco-Whole-Home-System/dp/B06WVCB862/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=mesh+wifi+system&qid=1606836634&sr=8-3', page, 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1616770813/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1', page );
    res.render('results', {data : data});
})

//server
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('server running');
})
----
```

---

Hope I am asking in right way, this is very first question I asked here. I'm just start learning node.js so haven't got much knowledge yet. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the calling of `getData` function, you cannot pass 4 parameters when it only accepts 2 at a time.

So, you can solve this by separating out the calls to the two pages like this:

```
let data1 = await getData('https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-Deco-Whole-Home-System/dp/B06WVCB862/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=mesh+wifi+system&qid=1606836634&sr=8-3', page);
let data2 = await getData('https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1616770813/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1', page );
let data = [data1, data2]
res.render('results', {data})
```

Comment: that is good idea to combine URL together, no error in console log but don't know why there no data display in my index page, either data1 or data2 only the ejs html frame. I try to figure out now, anyway I appreciate your suggestion.